# Крово- и слёзопролитный

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, раздельно-дефис, сложные-слова, неологизмы

Как правильно написать?

*Это была крово- и слёзопролитная война.*
*Это была крово и слёзопролитная война.*
*Это была крово-и-слёзопролитная война.*

Answer (score 2):

Если абстрагироваться от значения *особенного* слова (слёзопролитный), то предложение необходимо оформить с так называемым висячим дефисом:
**Это была крово- и слёзопролитная война.**

Дефис применяется при записи конструкций с однородными членами, имеющими общий конечный элемент, если все члены, кроме последнего, представлены только начальными элементами; такой дефис называют «висячим», например:
*шарико- и роликоподшипники; кино-, теле- и видеофильмы; как водо-, так и газоснабжение; не только англо- и франко-, но и русскоязычные тексты; до- или послеперестроечные процессы.*
[Дефис (§ 112)](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=59)

*Крово/пролитный* и *слёзо/пролитный* — общим конечным элементом сложных слов является "пролитный" (его и отделяем).

Но дело в том, что в словарях нет такого слова — слёзопролитная (слёзопролитный).
С конечным элементом "пролитный" имеется всего лишь одно слово, зафиксированное словарями, — [кровопролитный](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) (сопровождающийся пролитием большого количества крови).

В толковом словаре:
[проли́ть](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)
**3.** *что.* Заставить течь, струиться (обычно напоказ). ***Пролить слезу*** (*ирон.*; поплакать). *Пролить пот* (усердно, напряжённо потрудиться). ***Пролить (чью-либо) кровь*** (убить, ранить кого-либо). ***Пролить (свою) кровь** за кого-либо, что-либо* (*высок.*; пожертвовать жизнью или оказаться раненным, защищая кого-либо, что-либо).

Если Вы хотите употребить слово "слёзопролитный" в серьезном тексте (без иронии, издёвки, насмешки), я бы не рекомендовала Вам использовать этот неологизм.

Comment: А оправдано ли употребление буквы "ё" при таком словообразовании? В чём отличие от случая "сл**е**зоточивый"?

Comment: Порылась: есть с **ё**, есть с **е** (https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&ei=98LXX-zxEs36qwGGvZPwAw&start=10&sa=N&filter=0&ved=2ahUKEwisyciVoM7tAhVN_SoKHYbeBD4Q8NMDegQIBBA7&biw=1366&bih=657). Авторское представление — вещь необъяснимая. К войне — слёзопролитный — мне не нравятся оба варианта.

Comment: Да, ни в одной книге таких слов гугл не находит. Видимо, это "журнализм" чистой воды.

Comment: Кстати, в книгах широко распространено "слезоиспускательный" - это как минимум соответствует физиологическим описаниям в спец. литературе.

Comment: Теоретически можно обыграть что угодно. Вот (с ходу, по-быстрому): _слёзная точивость_ или _кровное течение_. Чем не новояз?

Comment: Разве что как поэтическую вольность можно простить. В общем случае это именно новояз, который не красит "авторов". Журналисты всего лишь подражают неудачным находкам в своей среде.

Comment: Ну-у... Я (как могла) попыталась отговорить Автора использовать это словцо. И про орфографию, как мне кажется, написала всё подробно. Или что-то пропустила? Или надо **подчеркнуть** в ответе знаковые слова: _абстрагироваться от значения особенного слова_?